# SAS parallel processing: Start k parallel jobs subsequently until N jobs are done

Tags: parallel-processing, sas

There might be a simple solution, but currently I cannot get my head around it. Maybe someone could help me out.

So I have the following problem:

I have in total `N` SAS jobs that I want to finish. As my resources on my machine are too limited to start all `N` jobs simultaneously, I only want to start say `k = 5` at the same time. Every time one job finishes, I want to start the next one. The order in which the jobs are completed is not important.

Currently, I let all `k=5` jobs finish before I start the next 5.
So here is the pseudo code, for what I am currently doing:

```
/*The following macro starts k threads*/
%macro parallel_processing(k);

options fullstimer autosignon=yes sascmd="sas -nonews -threads";

%global thread jj idlist;

/*These are the N ID numbers for the jobs*/
%let idlist = 1 2 3 4 5 ... N;
%let jj = 0;
%do %until(&jj.=N);
    %do thread = 1 %to &k.;
        %let jj = %eval(&thread.+&jj.);
         %syslput thread = &thread;
         %syslput jj = &jj.;
         %syslput idlist = &idlist.;

        rsubmit process=task&thread. wait=no sysrputsync=yes;

          %let id =%scan(%trim(&idlist.),&jj.); 
          /*Do the job*/
          %job(id);

        endrsubmit;
    %end;

    /* HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
       I want to wait for each job separately, and start a new one
       with an increased id. So that constantly k threads are busy.
    */

    /* Wait for all threads to finish */
    waitfor _all_ %do thread = 1 %to &k.;
        task&thread
    %end;

    /* GET RESULTS FROM THREADS */
    %do thread = 1 %to (&k.);
        rget task&thread;
    %end;

    /* SIGNOFF THREADS*/
    %do thread = 1 %to (&k.);
        signoff task&thread;
    %end;
%end;
%mend parallel_processing;

%parallel_processing(k);
```

Maybe somebody has a nice idea, I would be grateful! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `waitfor _any_ ...` instead of `waitfor _all_ ...`:

1. Start the first 5 tasks, keeping a note of which 5 tasks are active.
2. Wait for any one of them to finish and remove it from the list of active tasks.
3. Start the next task from the queue and add it to the list of active tasks.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until there are no tasks left in the queue.

You can use any method you like to keep track of which 5 tasks are currently active.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The question is how do I keep track of which 5 tasks are running? `LISTTASK` prints the results to the log file, how can I get access to the list of tasks currently running?

Comment: Check the status using the macro variable you defined with the CMACVAR= option on the RSUBMIT statement.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Works great :D